# ExtJs localstorage API

Tags: extjs, local-storage

Does ExtJs provide API's for managing local databases such as localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

There is Ext.data.LocalStorageProxy in [Sencha Touch](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/), but nothing in ExtJs yet.

Anyway, should be not a big problem to write your own LocalStore...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Ext 4.0 has now been released, with localStorage support.  Here are the [API docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage).

Answer (score 0):

Sencha's ExtJS 5 provides two ways to access LocalStorage:

- [Data LocalStorage](http://docs.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage)
- [Util LocalStorage](http://docs.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.LocalStorage)

The advantage of #1 versus #2 is that you can set up the LocalStorage as a Data Store.
The advantage of #2 versus #1 is that it supports Legacy IE.  Why the support? Because IE 7 and earlier versions do not support LocalStorage so it uses IE's userData Behavior storage mechanism.

You can find more information at the links provided.